# Need simple plot in R that helps to visualize (classification and interpretation)

Tags: r

I have 3 classes and 3 attributes in my dataset. I am looking for simple plot(other than boxplot or scatterplot or histogram) that helps in interpretation of classification.
Can anyone suggest?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is too vague as currently written. Consider providing a sample of your data and a description of what your goals are for the graphic.

Answer (score 2):

You said "attributes" by which I assumed you meant categorical data. But then you talked about plots that are appropriate for continuous data. Confusion reigns. Let's assume you want to apply plotting methods to categorical data. After you tabulate by the interaction of the 3 "attributes", then the usual method would be a barchart of frequencies, but there are also plotting methods in package `vcd` that may be more pleasing to the eye. 'strucplot' and 'mosaic' produce plots where the area is proportional to the frequencies in a contingency table.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vcd/vignettes/strucplot.pdf